# Get data from a checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get the info from a checked checkbox. What i'm doing is get data from an api and showing as checkbox. Here's a part of my code where also have a validation if at least one coupon is checked:

```
vm.sendData = function() {
  vm.apiData = couponApi.get({
    idOrder: vm.idOrder
  })
  .$promise
  .then(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Response.length; i++) {
      data.Response[i].Select = vm.all;
    }
    vm.coupons = data.Response;
    vm.combo = data.Response.length > 0;
  });
}

vm.selectAll = function() {
  vm.all = !vm.all;
  vm.coupons.forEach(function(o) {
    o.Select = vm.all;
  })
}

vm.submit = function() {
  var checked = 0;
  vm.coupons.forEach(function(o) {
    if (o.Select === true)
      checked += 1;
  })
  if (vm.all || checked > 0) {} else if (checked === 0) {
    alert("Select at least one coupon");
  }
}
```

How can i get the value of the checked checkbox? I'm using only Javascript and AngularJs.

Comment: in your `submit` function has `forEach` for `coupons` and checked `o.Select` so on that place you are able to get the value of checkbox if you set values from `coupon` as a checkbox value

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the checked value when you instantiate the control like this:

```
angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkboxModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
    }]);
```

Then you can check it based on the name you gave the value in the example the checkbox will have both `value1` and `value2` as properties when checked.

The documentation seems pretty straight forward.

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D